# How to solve ERROR ITMS-90529 on submit application compiled by Xcode 7 GM?

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7, application-loader

I had submitted the application via Application Loader 3.1. It shows *"invalid package Applications built with SDK 9.0 or later must be packaged as proper IPA files."*

[image]

I had received an Email on Sep 12 from Apple which allow to submit apps built by Xcode 7 GM.

[image]

Comment: Similar question on Apple Dev Forum,  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15542

Comment: Looks like your are uploading a ZIP file. How did you generate this ?

Comment: @NicolasBraun Application Loader needs a ZIP file to upload. It's generated by Mac's default compress function.

Comment: is this an iPhone app ? Application loader need's an IPA files which is generated XCode when exporting the Archive for App Store in the Organizer Panel. Have  a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW12) to see how to generate the proper xarchive file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran into the same problem today. Turns out Application Loader 3.2 now requires the file to be .ipa only. It for some reason still accepts .zip files but will fail with this error. So just change the file extension to .ipa, assuming the contents were properly generated.

Answer (score 11):

1. make a folder with name `Payload`.
2. put the compiled files into `Payload` folder.
3. compress folder to `Payload.zip` file, than change to `Payload.ipa`.

Comment: Perfect, this is really best approach now.

Answer (score 2):

Try convert your .APP to .IPA by command line:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}”
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem all you need to do is to submit .ipa file and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Trick worked for me: 
**Archive** and **Export** the build from organizer. Select “**Save for iOS AppStore Deployment**”.
This will generate a **ipa** file that application loader accepts and uploads without any problem.
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!